# unnamed unix domain socket send return with EACCES

Tags: sockets

I encountered an issue that, I sent 8 bytes data to an unnamed unix domain socket with noblocking setting, but failed with the returned errno is EACCES.

It's that any situation can make this happen ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the Linux man page, EACCES is returned if: Write permission is denied on the destination  socket  file,  or search  permission is denied for one of the directories the path prefix.  (See path_resolution(7).)
If this doesn't help, your question is missing information.

Comment: I run with root user, I cannt understand how EACCES comes...

Comment: Then your question doesn't contain nearly enough information to answer.